# HTML table formatting on mobile

Tags: html, css

Hey guys im trying to figure out why my table keeps doing this when I switch to the mobile version, ive tried multiple different CSS edits to fix it, but whenever I got into mobile it shows like this

[Table in mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vJWy.png)

Comment: Hi, What is the exact issue? I'm seeing that table is properly rendered on mobile devices. can you give us more details?

Comment: I want the top row to show as one line, as you can see the last 3 are squished to fit the mobile version.

I am unsure on how to fix it, I was thinking of potentially a scroll option - but my code would not work, unsure what is the best approach.

Here is my code: https://paste.centos.org/view/a8582cc1

Comment: Yeah, but to fix this problem better if you add ```overflow-x:auto``` style into the table elements.

Comment: I have tried that and that did not seem to work either

https://pastebin.com/8bcR2EVZ

I used the exact code in this example, just changed the table values
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_responsive

Comment: In your styles, remove this ```th, td{... word-wrap: break-word;}``` I think this is the issue.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_responsive This works properly on smaller screens with a horizontal scrollbar inside the table. You didn't saw any scrollbar?

Comment: Did not seem to work unfortunately. Is there another way I could problem solve this?

Comment: Ok I tried to directly copy that code from w3schools... Looks like the issue might be with shopify itself as it would not display the scroll bar

Do you have any other ideas to fix this?

Comment: Maybe! Another way to fix this, add some width to table head tags ```<th>``` whose text length is more. like this ```<th width="20%">```. It would helps. Do compare with your code https://jsbin.com/kebesel/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this** Modified some styles and added width to the `<th>` tags.

**CSS:**

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  font-size:13px;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}
th, td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: #eee;
}
  table#t01 th {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

**TABLE:**

```
<table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Bust</th>
    <th>Sleeve</th>
    <th width="20%">Shoulder</th>
    <th width="15%">Length</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>S</td>
    <td>102</td>
    <td>61</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>37</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>M</td>
    <td>106</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>46</td>
    <td>38</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>L</td>
    <td>110</td>
    <td>63</td>
    <td>47</td>
    <td>39</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```